# Writing unit test for Pattern annotation

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

```
@Data
public class SampleRequest {
    @Valid
    List<someRequest> someReq;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1)
    @Pattern(regexp = "^(https?|http)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]",
            message = "Invalid URL")
    String sampleURL;

    Integer Count;
}
```

I want to write unit test for the above to test the sampleURL for the annotations that I'm using like if I give any URL it should match to regex pattern. I went through following links [how to do unit test validation annotations in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55186100/how-to-do-unit-test-validation-annotations-in-spring), [How to test validation annotations of a class using JUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069956/how-to-test-validation-annotations-of-a-class-using-junit/29070276#29070276)  but they weren't of much help, I have setSampleURL function as well . so how can I write tests for sampleURL variable. Basically I want to write test for the regex pattern, i.e whether the value I am giving to sampleURL matches the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection and [AssertJ](https://assertj.github.io/doc/) it may look ugly, but its fast and simple without Spring context initialization

```java
    @Test
    void reflection() throws NoSuchFieldException {
        final String url = "https://example.com"; // your URL here for validation
        final String regexp = Arrays.stream(
                SampleRequest.class.getDeclaredField("sampleURL").getAnnotationsByType(Pattern.class)
            )
            .findFirst()
            .get()
            .regexp();
        Assertions.assertThat(url)
            .as("Ensure that regexp from annotation successfully matched url '%s'", url)
            .matches(regexp);
    }
```

Comment: what is SampleRequest here?

Comment: that's a class from your task in the description